# Use LogParser's graphic image output in an asp.net Page

Tags: asp.net, logparser

I would like to create another page with statistics about the usage of my ASP.NET project. Top page visited, etc, etc.

I wonder if it is possible to use LogParser to create the graphic images of the page?

The following use-case comes to my mind: Select startDate and endDate and use them in a LogParser QUERY to select top user, hours with most traffic, etc, and output this query as an image with a chart in it.

Is this feasible to do on server side?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible, you can use the CHART output format to save a chart to a gif or jpg, and then include that image in the page.

Comment: But how do I go about calling LogParser programaticaly ?

Comment: You'll have to use the COM scriptable interface, it's fully explained in the Log Parser documentation. There are also sample scripts to get you started.

Comment: I have found out how to do it. Already I'm creating a prototype page full of graphs:) Thank you very much Gabriele.